# Calling backing Bean and Javascript Function simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-1.2

Can anyone please help me in finding the solution?

I have a h:commandButton which calls a action and fires actionListener after that.
But due to change in requirements I have removed the action attribute and added onclick Javacript function which calls a customized dialog. So now, the actionListener is not being fired where i have set some values using the button value.

Please tell me if there is any alternative in solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use the below code inside the jquery

```
document.form[0].sumbit();
```

this line will submit the form to back end bean